# Using scope from route config within html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As a beginner with AngularJs I am looking into creating a single page application and I am having trouble converting some early code into more professional code. In doing this conversion I moved all my 'page' html into their own .html files. I am using ng-view to then display the proper html page inside of my ng-view div tag. Although after moving all the code something is now wrong with calling my methods. Specifically I think my error is within the app.config for route or within my .html files content for calling this information. If I remove the ng-controller div from my .html how do I still use the default controller set from app.config?

Here is my app.route setup:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function config($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        });

}]);
```

Then here is my mainController setup:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'LoginService', function ($scope, LoginService) {
        //Controller logic goes here 



        this.isValid = function (username, password) {

            var EmailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
            var PasswordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$/;

            var EmailReg = new RegExp(EmailRegex);
            var PasswordReg = new RegExp(PasswordRegex);

            var em = EmailReg.test(username);
            var pas = PasswordReg.test(password);

            //alert("Hello dude! Email:" + em + " Password:" + pas + "\n" + username + " " + password );

            if (em && pas) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        };

        this.user =
            {
                Message: 'Sign in',
                ButtonMessage: 'Sign in Bailey',
                TempUser: '',
                TempPassword: '',
                FirstName: '',
                LastName: '',
                Role: '',
                AuthHash: null,
                FinalUser: $scope.Username, 
                FinalPassword: $scope.Password,
            };

        $scope.user = this.user;


        this.Authenicate = function (Username, Password) {
            LoginService.Login(Username, Password).then(function (ResponseData)
            {

                var readAbleObject = angular.fromJson(angular.fromJson(ResponseData));
                $scope.user.FirstName = readAbleObject.FirstName;
                $scope.user.LastName = readAbleObject.LastName;
                $scope.user.Role = readAbleObject.Role;
                $scope.user.AuthHash = readAbleObject.AuthHash;
                $scope.user.Username = readAbleObject.Username;
                $scope.user.Password = readAbleObject.Password;
                $scope.user.Message = "Welcome " + $scope.user.FirstName;
                $scope.user.ButtonMessage = "Sign " + $scope.user.FirstName + " " + $scope.user.LastName + " out";

                $scope.clearInput();

            });
        };

        $scope.clearInput = function () {
            this.user.TempUser = null;
            this.user.TempPassword = null;
        };


    }]);
```

My html waiting for views to load into them:

```
<div id="MainDiv" data-ng-app="GApp">
    <div id="LoginDiv" class="wrap" data-ng-view="">

    </div>
</div>
```

My .html files content:

```
<div data-ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
<div id="HomeHtml">
    <link href="Content/Markup/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <p class="form-title">{{user.Message}}</p>
    <form name="login" class="login" novalidate>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Susquehanna Software Email" data-ng-model="user.TempUser" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" data-ng-model="user.TempPassword" />
        <input type="submit" value="{{user.ButtonMessage}}" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" data-ng-disabled="isValid(user.TempUser, user.TempPassword)" data-ng-click="Authenicate(user.TempUser, user.TempPassword)" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using controller as syntax, if you write ctrl.user.TempPassword or generally append ctrl before user, then it should work.

You are on the right track, you do not need to write $scope.user = this.user. Its good practice to use controller as syntax.

```
.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
})
```

Comment: That is one solution however I want to use the default controller set from within the app.config logic. That doesn't have a ctrl alias so how do I use that information. The potential answer I am going to mark is to just set everything to $scope rather than this in my controller logic.

Comment: I have added an example of how you would do the controller as in app.config, its up to you to choose the answer, just saying it is considered one of the good practices. https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes

Comment: That just determined this will be the answer to the question, thank you. Before I mark it so within my controller logic I can leave the methods as this.isValid = ... and call them in html using ctrl.isValid?

Comment: Yes, that should work, but see the link I have posted above, that shows a lot of the best practices, or at least to avoid common mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I know this is outside the scope of this question but any links for information on working with the view would be amazing. I currently have a nav bar which can change the entire view, but I would like to have multiple divs and all of them with views in them so a main view and then maybe something happens on the page and that view just changes to something else. And so on.

Comment: This might help: http://www.bogotobogo.com/AngularJS/AngularJS_ui-route-vs-ngRoute-multiple-views-nested-views.php

Answer (score 0):

for functions to be visible to your view from the controller they need assigning to the `$scope` object e.g. `$scope.Authenticate = this.Authenticate`

Comment: So within my controller logic instead of naming this.isValid = function() ... I should just do $scope.isValid = function() ...

Comment: that would also do the same thing, you have already done it with the user object which is why that part works